# What info is available to all iOS 5+ & Android apps automatically?

Tags: android, ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to make a detailed blueprint for a Twitter app I'm designing: both my first native app & my first time playing with Twitter's API. I'm curious as to **what information is available to all apps when the user has authenticated with the device itself but hasn't granted my app read & write access yet**. Do iOS & Android give up the user's ID before asking them to authenticate? And what's the deal with iOS 4 support - will there have to be a fallback that has a username:password form? And since I've never used an Android device for more than 5 minutes: is Twitter support similar on there?

Additionally, has anyone seen a great re-imagining of the sign-in process? Now that we have Twitter support built into devices, shouldn't there be a handful of neat sign-in layouts? The ugly text fields are gone, allowing user focus & energy to shift to the entire screen; that should make way for stylish animations... no?

As always, TIA!